# accessing external MSSQL database from magento to display more data

Tags: database, external

I am trying to pull information from an external mssql database for extra product information and display them on the product view page.

I have read other similar posts, but they are for mysql only and not complete. 
I am using Magento 1.9, Ubuntu 15.04.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189390/magento-connections-to-two-databases) is exactly what you need.
You can define multiple database connections in your config.xml

```
<!-- osCommerce db/read/write -->
<oscommercedb>
    <connection>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <username>root</username>
        <password>pass</password>
        <dbname>oscommerce_database_name</dbname>
        <model>mysql4</model>
        <initstatements>SET NAMES utf8</initstatements>
        <type>pdo_mysql</type>
        <active>1</active>
    </connection>
</oscommercedb>
<oscommercedb_write>
    <connection>
        <use>oscommercedb</use>
    </connection>
</oscommercedb_write>
<oscommercedb_read>
    <connection>
        <use>oscommercedb</use>
    </connection>
</oscommercedb_read>
<!-- end osCommerce db -->
```

and then simply call the resource like this

```
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('oscommercedb');
```

In the original answr you will find some more info, but it is possible at least.

Comment: This isn't MSSQL

Comment: Right. Have you tried it at least or searched the allowed <type>?

Comment: No, but I notice your example uses `pdo_mysql` which doesn't seem correct.  Is that type compatible?